# How can I get a textarea from model+ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, forms, model

models.py=>

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from datetime import date
import datetime
from django import forms
from django.forms import Textarea

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class PostModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

But I get a text input not textarea for `models.TextField()`. Is that a reason of css?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think this [section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) in the documentation should be useful to solve the problem.

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea

class PostModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        widgets = {
            'content': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}),
        }
```

Comment: It's models.CharField(), not forms.CharField(), posting complete example may help.

Comment: Sorry, my previous answer assumed you were using `forms` directly instead of `ModelForm`. The new link should provide the information that you need.

Comment: I have tried that but that didn't work, i don't see any height or weight for that textarea.

Comment: He used cols & rows, but you can just as easily put a class into the attrs and style off of that (or put the styles in directly, but why hard-code presentation logic that far down into the back-end?)

Comment: @Tom I used the same example as in the documentation, but you're right, it's better to keep presentation and business logic separate.

Comment: @jcollado - no worries, I more meant that for the OP.

Answer (score 11):

Alternative to jcollardo's solution (same result, different syntax):

```
from django import forms

class PostModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

Comment: and add col/row attrs like: content = forms.CharField(widget=Textarea(attrs={'cols':80, 'rows': 20}))

Answer (score 1):

You are using models not forms, which means you can't use textarea properly. Instead you can try TextField:

```
field_name = models.TextField( **options)
```